# Bootstrap Table with Fixed Column on top when scrolling down

Tags: css, laravel

I am building a table with Laravel for a web page. I would like to fix columns on the top when scrolling down so that one can still the column names.

Is there a way to do that in Laravel or with Bootstrap?

```
<div class="card-body" style="height:400px; width:99%; overflow:scroll;">
    <!--TABLE-->
    <h5>ED Visits Suspected Drug Overdose Data</h5>
    <div class="table">
        <table class="table mb-0">
            <thead>
                <tr style="vertical-align:center;">
                    <th scope="col">Ohio County</th>
                    <th scope="col">2016 Q3 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2016 Q4 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2017 Q1 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2017 Q2 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2017 Q3 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2017 Q4 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2018 Q1 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2018 Q2 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2018 Q3 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2018 Q4 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2019 Q1 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2019 Q2 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2019 Q3 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2019 Q4 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2020 Q1 </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!--data and codes-->
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Before Scrolling and After Scrolling]

Comment: can you show your code for your table header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a `position: sticky;` on the table's `thead` and it will stick to the top with `top: 0;`. More on `position` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

```css
thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-body" style="height:400px; width:99%; overflow:scroll;">
  <!--TABLE-->
  <h5>ED Visits Suspected Drug Overdose Data</h5>
  <div class="table">
    <table class="table mb-0">
      <thead>
        <tr style="vertical-align:center;">
          <th scope="col">Ohio County</th>
          <th scope="col">2016 Q3 </th>
          <th scope="col">2016 Q4 </th>
          <th scope="col">2017 Q1 </th>
          <th scope="col">2017 Q2 </th>
          <th scope="col">2017 Q3 </th>
          <th scope="col">2017 Q4 </th>
          <th scope="col">2018 Q1 </th>
          <th scope="col">2018 Q2 </th>
          <th scope="col">2018 Q3 </th>
          <th scope="col">2018 Q4 </th>
          <th scope="col">2019 Q1 </th>
          <th scope="col">2019 Q2 </th>
          <th scope="col">2019 Q3 </th>
          <th scope="col">2019 Q4 </th>
          <th scope="col">2020 Q1 </th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>You</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>You</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>You</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>You</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>You</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>You</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>You</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>You</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>123</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </thead>
      <!--data and codes-->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```